# Background location updates in IOS7

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

Whether apple has removed **background location updates** in **IOS7** when app is running in background?

If yes, Can i get any **Proof/apple document** regarding this **OR** 
Can i get any **objective-C code** to test this?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to see the video "What’s New in Core Location" from https://developer.apple.com/wwdc/videos/ it deals a lot with background location updates in iOS7